# How to convert a logo to grayscale in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion, file-format

I have a logo that has color gradients and I need to convert it to grayscale in Photoshop or in Illustrator and get a good result.

I tried to convert my logo in Illustrator but the result is unbalanced.

Instead I want to use Photoshop. What would be the steps to converting a logo to grayscale in Photoshop and which format I should save it for printing without any logo distortion?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/102931/convert-complex-artwork-into-single-color/103005#103005

Comment: If the logo is in Illustrator.. change the fill/stroke greyscale values so that it **is** balanced. Don't use Photoshop. There's **no reason on Earth** you need to create a raster file merely to convert to greyscale.

Comment: @Scott Thanks- I really like your answers. You are a real problem solver.

Comment: Use can also use the `Black and White` Adjustments in Photoshop. Then fine tune the color ranges. `Image >> Adjustments >> Black & White...` or Shortcut `Alt+Shift+Ctr+B`

Answer (score 3):

**You should always design your logo in black in white first.**

---

Since you are past that part, converting in Photoshop goes like this:

1. Complete all of you editing before converting the original image.
2. Save a backup copy as a PSD before converting. This step is so you can edit the original version of the image after the conversion.
3. Flatten the file before converting it. The interaction of colors between layer blending modes change when the mode changes. However if your file has vector text layers you shouldn’t flatten. If flattening might create some undesirable effects.
4. Choose *Image → Mode* and the mode you want from the submenu. Modes not available for the active image appear dimmed in the menu.
   Images are flattened when converted to multichannel, bitmap, or indexed-color mode, because these modes do not support layers.

[image]

After converting you can adjust the curves, levels, and brightness and contrast.

---

---

If your logo is a vector format you can easily convert it to black and white in Illustrator.

[image]

Then you can adjust the intensity using the saturation settings: *Edit → Edit Colors → Saturate.*

[image]

---

---

For printing format it really depends on what the logo is being printed on but the usual standard is a PDF. In a pinch I would use a TIFF or a JPG with a DPI of 300 or more but a vector PDF is really the way to go.

Take note that your quality will be lower if your artwork is raster or you take your vector art and rasterize it in Photoshop.

Comment: Completely unnecessary to write that at the beginning, as it is it comes out extremely *harsh* (due to **BOLD CAPS BIG LETTERS**)

Comment: Removed caps but I stand by my bolding. It is THE most important thing in Logo design.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you there. I don't like the method used to give over that message. It may not be all caps, but it is still quite passive aggressive and should be written out much more nicely.